# Why I cannot reset state of react component?

Tags: reactjs

I try to reset react component state by using preserved initial variable but this is not worked. What is the problem here?

First have I created a base state variable "baseState" then I will used to reset react state. but it not worked,

Here I create a sample program below,

```
class Product extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
      super(props); 
      this.baseState = {isLoggedIn: true, loader:false, inputs : { name :null, category_id:null }};
      this.state=this.baseState;
    }

    render {
      (<Form>{/* form inputs */}</Form>)
    }
   
    // this is a onChange select event for update input values.
    selectInputChange(e){            
      let stateInputs=this.state.inputs;
      stateInputs[e.target.name]=e.target.value;
      let inputErrors=this.state.errors;
      let error=this.validateFormInput(e.target.name,e.target.value);           
       inputErrors[e.target.name]=error?error:null;
       this.setState( prev =>{
        return{
            ...prev, inputs: stateInputs, errors:inputErrors
        }
      });

       console.log(this.baseState);     // here value is updated.
   }

   handleFormSubmit(){
      // after insert record through axios. then i try to reset like
      this.setState(this.baseState);
      // but state is not updated here.
   }

    
}
export default withRouter(Product);
```

I am beginner to reactjs so help me to solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: Is it calling handleSubmit function?

Comment: yes @Md.MoshfiqurRahmanRony this was a form on submit event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making `this.state` point to *the same object* as `this.baseState` (variables are just aliasses to "things that start at some specific address in memory"), so whether you make changes using one variable or the other, the actual "thing" you're working with is the same thing.

As you're discovering, `this.setState(this.baseState)` will do nothing, because you're updating the current state with itself, and is the same as saying `this.setState(this.state)`.

If you want a state that you can truly reset to, use a function that generates a *new* object each time you call it:

```
class Product extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
      super(props); 
      this.state = this.getInitialState();
    }
    getInitialState() {
      return {
        isLoggedIn: true,
        loader: false,
        inputs: {
          name: null,
          category_id: null
        }
      };
    }
    ...
```

And then whenever you want to reset your component, you can call `this.setState(this.getInitialState())`, which will reset all the properties that are relevant to your initial state (while leaving anything else entirely untouched - you won't be removing any state values not covered by the initial state object).